# How to call method on subclass with Java/Processing?

Tags: java, processing

In my Sketch I have an array of UI objects.  In the array is a Frame object.  Frame is a class that inherits from the UI class.  I'm trying to call a method in the Frame object, but I'm getting the error 'The function AddChild(MyScratch.Frame) does not exist'.  Now, I can fix this error by casting the UI object to a Frame and then calling the method, but I don't want to constantly to that.  Is there any way to fix this?  Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
private UI[] uis = new UI[] {
    new Frame(10, 10, 100, 100)
};

public void setup() {

    size(600, 600);

    // call the AddChild(UI u) method of Frame, causes an error
    // I know I could do ((Frame)uis[0]).AddChild(...), but I don't
    // want to do that constantly
    uis[0].AddChild(new Frame(0, 0, 100, 100));

}

public void draw() {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the method `AddChild` is not in the `UI` class, you can't call this function with a reference to a `UI` class.

you can choose one of the following:

1. Add the `AddChild` to the `UI` class
2. Use a `Frame` array instead of `UI` Array
3. Check if the instance in the `UI` array is a `Frame` and cast it.